# Route specific DelegatingHandler when using AttributeRouting

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting

I am trying to add a custom delegating handle to a specific route when using attribute routing. I looked through online resources and cannot figure out a way to do it.

The only way to specify custom delegating handle seems to be through MapHttpRoute. When I add the handler for the route through MapHttpRoute (along with attribute routing), I get an error that the action could be found in the controller -
"MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'TestQuery' that matches the request."}

Is there any other way I can add a customer delegating handler for a specific route?

PS: The delegating handler I am trying to add is something that already exists and I cannot modify the handler to check for specific routes there.

Comment: Web API allows custom message handlers to be added to the chain between the HttpServer and HttpRoutingDispatch
classes. Unless I am mistaken it is the HttpRoutingDispatch classes that match the request to a route. The only way that I could see that the handler would be specific to a single route would be if the handler checked the request to determine if the destination matched a specific route.

Comment: Any luck solving this problem?